# Where do I put previously made HTML files in a Rails application?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I made a website with Twitter bootstrap and the design is finished in terms of all the HTML and CSS.

Now I need to add functions like making an account and blogging.  I decided to use Ruby on Rails to do this, but I have no idea where to put the files and how to connect them.

So far I have figured out that I want to put them in the "views" folder and have it say, for example, "index.html.erb" but I don't know if that goes into another folder in "views" or how any of that works.

I also don't know where to put all the CSS and JavaScript incorporated with bootstrap.

Comment: it has nothing to do with code though, only file directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Rails conventions, views should go in a dir that mirrors the model name (plural), which also aligns with the controller name.  i.e.  model = user, views dir = users, controller = users_controller.rb.  You should read through at least the first few Rails guides; esp this [layout and rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) one:

RE the bootstrap portion of this question, just use the [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) gem and follow the instructions for including it in your application.scss and application.js.

Comment: awesome thanks, but what is the purpose of model and controller and how do you set them up?

Comment: and the gem wont work for me, I have modified many of the bootstrap elements so it would be completely different

Comment: Large topic - too much to really cover here.  Read the Rails getting started guide and other Rails MVC explanations / tutorials.  RE Bootstrap customizations - you can instead drop in the css files into `app/assets/stylesheets` and then import what you need in your application.scss.  Alternatively, use them gem and then just override variables before you import bootstrap.